# How to get "Var1" value of dumper in perl

Tags: perl, data-dumper

When i use below code then it gives output, But i want "width", "file_media_type", "file_ext" values, But I am unable to get this value in individual. I am very new with Perl Please help me!

Code

```
use warnings ;
use strict;
use Image::Info qw[image_info];
use Data::Dumper;

my $file = 'd:\perl\test\a.jpg';
my $info = Dumper(image_info($file));
print $info;
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = {
          'width' => 45,
          'file_media_type' => 'image/png',
          'file_ext' => 'png',
          'PNG_Chunks' => [
                            'IHDR',
                            'gAMA',
                            'cHRM',
                            'IDAT',
                            'IEND'
                          ],
          'Chunk-cHRM' => '  z%  Çâ  ·   ÇF  u0  O`  :ù  ?o',
          'PNG_Filter' => 'Adaptive',
          'color_type' => 'RGB',
          'height' => 20,
          'Gamma' => '0.45454',
          'resolution' => '1/1',
          'SampleFormat' => 'U8',
          'Compression' => 'Deflate'
        };
```

Comment: `my $info = image_info($file); print $info->{width};` See [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

`image_info($file)` returns a hash reference. Looking at the dump you know the keys available (the keys are strings before `=>`)

```
    $info = image_info($file);

    foreach my $key ( qw/width file_media_type file_ext/ ){
        print "$key:$info->{$key}\n";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much,

could you give me any reference for making my concept more clear like you?

Comment: I'm not quite follow your question, could you reformulate it? What is your concept?

Comment: I just want to make my skill sharp. if you give any reference like blog, books, etc. Then it is helpful for me

Comment: may be this help http://search.cpan.org/~srezic/Image-Info-1.38/lib/Image/Info.pm ? It's a description of Image-Info package you use

Comment: Thanks for this one. But I am taking about over all Perl not for a particular module